# How to login in website using facebook id

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I have made a website on which a user has to log in using a username and password. I have seen these in so many website, we can connect through facebook account. And I want to add the same to my web site. How is it possible,using php sdk or the javascript sdk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The team at Facebook has spent considerable time documenting this, I would suggest you start there:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web#login
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

Answer (score 1):

If possible, I would do like [dracolytch writes here](http://forum.developers.facebook.com/viewtopic.php?pid=192324) and create a level of abstraction for both OpenID and Facebook. He is willing to share his code.

Answer (score -2):

Those links are what Facebook likes to call "Badges." Go to your profile. Scroll all the way to the bottom. On the lower left hand column you should see a link that says "Create Profile Badge." Click that. From there you can edit a Badge to show the info you'd like. At the end, it will give you some html code that you can copy and paste into another website or blog. When people click on your Badge, they will get sent directly to your Facebook info box.
Source(s):

http://www.facebook.com/badges.php

Comment: That's not what he want. Badges are just to display your fb profile in your site. It can't be used for logging in