# Facebook Login on my Forum

Tags: facebook, registration, forum

I run a small business and we are about to overhaul our website and forum. I have looked through the Q&A in this section and havent found anything yet. Is it possible to allow my customers to sign in to my forum on my website through facebook?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to login in website using facebook id](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012203/how-to-login-in-website-using-facebook-id)

Answer (score 3):

yes it is possible.

you can use this http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/.

here you can find facebook API for your site as your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe instead of trying to update your current one, which can be a nightmate, you could start from scratch and import any of the old users or posts you need.

The link below is an example of SMF forum and SA facebook integration but slightly modified to allow full integration.

http://www.albentley.co.uk/portfolio/index.php/websites/59